# Optimize multiple exit points with cleanup code

Tags: c++, optimization, refactoring

I am implementing a serial communication protocol. In the receive function of this implementation I have multiple exit points with duplicated code for clean-up. I am not sure if the expression SESE is valid in case of structural/OO programming languages. I am using C++.
This is not MCVE but just the structure that I have in my code. The code looks something like:

```
bool receive()
{
  bool status = false;
  initializeCommunication();
  if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
  {
     cleanupCode();
     return status;
  }
  processFirstParam();
  if (receiveTwoBytesIsNotWhatExpected())
  {
    cleanupCode();
    return status;
  }
  processSecondParam();
  if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
  {
    cleanupCode();
    return status;
  }
  processThirdParam();
  if (receiveFourBytesIsNotWhatExpected())
  {
    cleanupCode();
    return status;
  }
  processFourthParam();
  status = true;
  cleanupCode();
  return status;
}
```

I want to refactor it. One way to do it will be using a kind of state-machine, e.g.:

```
bool receive()
{
  status = true;
  state = START;
  while (status && state != POSTENDED)
  {
    switch(state)
    {
      case START:
        initializeCommunication();
        state = RECEIVEFIRSTONEBYTE;
        // fall-through
      case RECEIVEFIRSTONEBYTE:
        if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
        {
          status = false;
        }
        else
        {
          processFirstParam();
          state = RECEIVESECONDTWOBYTES;
        }
          break;
      case RECEIVESECONDTWOBYTES:
       if (receiveTwoBytesIsNotWhatExpected())
       {
         status = false;
       }
       else
       {
         processSecondParam();
         state = RECEIVETHIRDONEBYTE:
       }
       break;
       case RECEIVETHIRDONEBYTE:
        if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
        {
          status = false;
        }
        else
        {
          processThirdParam();
          state = RECEIVEFOURTHFOURBYTES;
        }
        break;
        case RECEIVEFOURTHFOURBYTES:
        if (receiveFourBytesIsNotWhatExpected())
        {
          status = false;
        }
        else
        {
          processFourthParam();
          state = ENDED;
        }
        break;
        case ENDED:
          status = true;
          state = POSTENDED;
        break;
    }
  }
  cleanupCode();
  return status;
}
```

Third way to write the above code will be with nested if statements that will generate four levels nested if statements but that will be concise.
What is the optimized way of writing this kind of code and what are the pros and cons of each of them.

Comment: Consider using pattern "Chain of responsibility"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a cleanup guard:

```cpp
bool receive()
{
    bool status = false;
    initializeCommunication();
    struct CleanupGuard
    {
        ~CleanupGuard()
        {
           cleanupCode();
        }
    } g;
    if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
    {
        return status;
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Inline function:

```cpp
namespace
{
   inline bool doReceive()
   {
       // [...]
   }
}

bool receive()
{
    initializeCommunication();
    bool status = doReceive();
    cleanupCode();
    return status;
}
```

Loop approach:

```cpp
bool receive()
{
    bool status = false;
    initializeCommunication();
    do
    {
        if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
        {
            status = false;
            break;
        }
        // [...]
    }
    while(false);
    cleanupCode();
    return status;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the solution with inline function seems more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

While the usage of labels and `goto` is generally frowned upon, this is usually one of the situations where many would consider it okay to use.

So instead of having e.g.

```
if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
{
  cleanupCode();
  return status;
}
...
```

You would have something like

```
if (receiveOneByteIsNotWhatExpected())
{
  goto end;
}
```

And in the end of the function:

```
  processFourthParam();
  status = true;
end:
  cleanupCode();
  return status;
}
```

This will minimize the duplication of common code, and is the cornerstone of the "one return only" or "single entry, single exit" principles.

Comment: I am not sure if my code reviewer will be happy to see "goto" in the source. But other than removing the duplicated code what benefit does it give in terms of runtime.

Comment: @masterop One shouldn't consider goto per se bad just because it was abused so many times... If used properly, one can achieve quite clean code, and this answer proves it...

Comment: @masterop In terms of runtime performance, probably no difference at all. In terms of maintainability (which I consider more important) there's a big difference IMO.

Comment: This only works if your cleanup is simple; If you need to add multiple cleanup steps (depending on where you `goto` from), this solution quickly becomes ugly, requiring you to jump all over the place just to track the possible states of the cleanable data. You are better off with RAII (see @Aconcagua's `CleanupGuard`).

Comment: @Aconcagua, this code has non-obvious side-effects (like your next programmer saying "but `goto` is perfectly acceptable in our code base - see? it's used there! - so I can use it here and in that other place as well").

Comment: @utnapistim Well, *that*'s an interesting kind of side effect... But actually, this programmer is right, he *can* use goto - if she uses it the right way... Coding conventions would be needed to define a clear border between good and evil use. Admitted, it is really not easy to draw such a border, so most CC go the easy way and simply forbid it entirely... On the other hand, there is so much bad code out there even without goto. Ever thought of why e. g. MISRA is *dozens* of pages long (MISRA-C 2004: 111)?

Comment: In the end, no matter if with or without goto, writing good code requires some common sense between the involved developpers what goog code actually is (-> coding conventions) and the discipline of all them to follow this common sensce...